# Sencha Touch 2 Build Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: build-automation, sencha-touch-2, minify

I'm trying to build Sencha Touch 2 application for production, but get an error.
When i run testing build - 'sencha app build testing' I see **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL** 
in app.js (testing build - so it's not minimized).

And the content at the error line is

```
п»їExt.define("App.controller.SomeController",
```

As I see sencha inserts some strange symbols before **Ext.define** that cannot be interpeted.
They appears before each definition of any of my classes.

I check encoding for files (utf-8) and line-endings (Windows - CR-LF)

My PC running on Win 7 SP1 x86

Please, help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the folowing lines in app.json fixed production build. However testing build still failed.

```
 /**
 * File / directory name matchers to ignore when copying to the builds, must be valid regular expressions
 */
"ignore": [
    "\.svn$"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some error within your code. Check the developer tools console for any errors since if there are errors, it will most probably not build successfully. S

tart by adding only a custom panel for instance not the whole app. Then try and build the simplest of apps, like a Hello World and check if the problem persists.

Most likely, the build will be successful. If this is the case, start adding little by little until the problem occurs and that way you can recognise where the problem relies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the code is corred. Seems some issues with svn. Igonre svn files in app.json helped to solve the issue.